# How to access oauth2 token response in a UWP app

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, uwp, imgur

I am developping an UWP application that uses the [Imgur.API](http://imgurapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) imgur api wrapper.

I open the oauth2 authorization url in the user's web browser using

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(imgur.getAuthorizationUrl());
```

Where

> imgur.getAuthorizationUrl()

is the result of

```
var authorizationUrl = endpoint.GetAuthorizationUrl(Imgur.API.Enums.OAuth2ResponseType.Token);
```

I use OAuth2ResponseType.Token because Imgur's documentation says

> Only token should be used, as the other methods have been deprecated.

How to know what redirect url to use and how to access the token data in a uwp application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the redirect URL, you will need to register your application in the [imgur developer portal](https://imgur.com/signin?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.imgur.com%2Foauth2%2Faddclient). 
Once registered, you will get the `client_id`, `secret_key` and `redirect_url` that you need to perform the OAuth2 flow.

To authenticate the user in you UWP application, you should use the [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227025) which will handle all the OAuth2 flow for you.

Here is the sample code extract from the class documentation:

```
 String FacebookURL = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + FacebookClientID.Text + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(FacebookCallbackUrl.Text) + "&scope=read_stream&display=popup&response_type=token";

System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(FacebookURL);
System.Uri EndUri = new Uri(FacebookCallbackUrl.Text);

WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                        WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                        StartUri,
                                        EndUri);
if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
{
    OutputToken(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString());
}
else if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
{
    OutputToken("HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString());
}
else
{
    OutputToken("Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus.ToString());
}
```

You can get a full sample here: [WebAuthenticationBroker sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAuthenticationBroker)

Comment: I will try that. Thanks